# How to flag current transactions in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large financial data set. Each row is a transaction. Col A is the company name, Col B is transaction date and Col C is valuation post transaction. I want to create Col D to indicate the most current (latest) transaction for each company. Here is simplified example of my data set - I need the formula for Col D, but have not been able to figure it out!

[image: Example Data Set]

Comment: Are company names always sorted like in your screencap?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 =IF(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)=B2,"Current","")
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up just sorting by company and then by date and using simple =IF(A2=A3,"Not Current","Current") - I'm sure this isn't the best way, but it worked.